# SPARQL: extract distinct values from dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to extract graphs for 5 individuals who are Film(or movies) from DBPedia.

My query is:

*ParameterizedSparqlString qs = new ParameterizedSparqlString( "" +

                    "construct{?s ?p ?o}"+
                    "where{?s a http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film ."+
                        "?s ?p ?o"} OFFSET 0 LIMIT 5" );*

I get the following result:

1- http://dbpedia.org/resource/1001_Inventions_and_the_World_of_Ibn_Al-Haytham http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film .

2- http://dbpedia.org/resource/1001_Inventions_and_the_World_of_Ibn_Al-Haytham http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing .

3- http://dbpedia.org/resource/1001_Inventions_and_the_World_of_Ibn_Al-Haytham http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q386724 .

4- http://dbpedia.org/resource/1001_Inventions_and_the_World_of_Ibn_Al-Haytham http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Wikidata:Q11424 .

5- http://dbpedia.org/resource/1001_Inventions_and_the_World_of_Ibn_Al-Haytham http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Work .

Problem:
The same film is returned 5 times as all the class: Film, Thing, Q386724,WIKIdata:Q11424, and Work are equivalent class (or Subclass relation exist).

My question:

I want to return once the triple

```
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/1001_Inventions_and_the_World_of_Ibn_Al-Haytham>    
 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> 
 <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .
```

and filter out the other 4 triples.

How do it please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You asked for `?s ?p ?o`, so you'll get among the results other classes of which `?s` is a member, regardless if they are equivalent or not.

Comment: Thank you. But How i can i return back only the triple of ?s related to Film class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this query

```
construct {?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .}
where { ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film>. }
limit 5
```

Comment: Thank you. This query will return 5 differents Film. Which is very good but i need the other triplet of each individual, like name, duration etc.

Comment: @user2869180 [with name](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect+%3Fs+%3Fname%0D%0A%0D%0A%7B%3Fs+a+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FFilm%3E.%0D%0Aoptional%7B%0D%0A%3Fs+foaf%3Aname+%3Fname%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alimit+5&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: @user2869180 [with name, writer, producer](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect+%3Fs+%3Fname+%3Fwriter+%3Fproducer%0D%0A%0D%0A%7B%3Fs+a+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FFilm%3E.%0D%0Aoptional%7B%0D%0A%3Fs+foaf%3Aname+%3Fname%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aoptional%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fs++dbo%3Awriter+%3Fwriter%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aoptional%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fs+dbo%3Aproducer+%3Fproducer%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alimit+5&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: @WilliamKinaan those are SELECT queries, not CONSTRUCT. You need a sub-SELECT in a CONSTRUCT query, see the answer of scotthenninger below

Comment: While this query may or may not be what OP wants, note that for CONSTRUCT queries with sufficiently simply WHERE parts, you can just do [CONSTRUCT WHERE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#constructWhere).  That is, this query is simply `construct where { ?s a dbo:Film } limit 5`

Answer (score 5):

I think the following should work for you:

```
CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o}
WHERE {
  {  SELECT DISTINCT ?s
     WHERE {
        ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .
     } LIMIT 5
  }
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
```