# Sparql CONSTRUCT with DISTINCT

Tags: sparql, distinct

```sql
PREFIX content: <http://example.com/content#>
construct { ?s content:field ?o}
WHERE { ?s content:field ?o }
```

90% of all the `?o` I get here are the same URI `<http://example.com/name>`.

I'm trying to find a way to filter out all quads that have the same value for `?o`, so in the end I get a list of quads which are unique by its `?o`

I tried `DISTINCT ?o CONSTRUCT{...}` but from what I saw you cant use `DISTINCT` on a `CONSTRUCT`.

How would you filter the returned list of quads

Comment: Subquery with `SELECT DISTINCT` to pull the data you want from the existing store, wrapped in `CONSTRUCT` based on those results. See <https://stackoverflow.com/a/38256785/241164>. (Note that you're `SELECT`ing and `CONSTRUCT`ing triples here, not quads...)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to get. `CONSTRUCT` returns i) a **set** of ii) RDF **triples**. So, can you please provide an example with sample data + expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to find a way to filter out all quads that have the same
>   value for `?o`, so in the end I get a list of quads which are unique by
>   its `?o`

if it does not matter which exact value is bound to `?s`, then a sub-select with a `group by ?o` is the way to go. Use `(SAMPLE(?s) as ?subj)` e.g. something like:
`

```
PREFIX content: <http://example.com/content#>
construct { ?s content:field ?o}
WHERE { 
    { select ?o (SAMPLE(?subj) as ?s) 
        { ?subj content:field ?o } 
    group by ?o 
    } 
}
```

`